# If $k^{\log_{2}5}=16$ then find $k^{{(\log_{2}5})^2} = $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$k^{\log_{2}5}=16$$ then find 
$$k^{{(\log_{2}5})^2}$$

Note: the exponent(entire log) is squared unlike the value
Inside the log squared.

Comment: Solve your first equation for $k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=k^{(\log_25)^2}$. Taking $\log_5$ on both sides,

$$\log_5 x=\log_5\left[k^{(\log_25)(\log_25)}\right]$$
$$\log_5 x=\log_25\cdot\log_5\left[k^{\log_25}\right]$$
$$\log_5 x=\log_25\cdot\log_516$$

$$\log_5x=\log_216$$
$$\log_5x=4$$
So$$x=5^4=625$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

Use exponent laws:

$$k^{a^2}=k^{a \cdot a}= \left(\color{blue}{k^a}\right)^a$$

In your case $a=\log_25$ and you know the value of $\color{blue}{k^a}$.

Or, put differently:

> $$k^{\log_{2}5}=16$$

Raise both sides of this equality to the power $\log_25$: the left-hand side is then exactly what you need to find, the right-hand side is the answer (although you can simplify!).

Answer (score 2):

Let $\log_25=a,\implies2^a=5$

and $k^a=16$

$k^{a^2}=(k^a)^a=16^a=(2^a)^4=?$

Answer (score 1):

Since $k=16^{\frac{1}{\log_25}},$ we obtain:
$$k^{\log^2_25}=16^{\log_25}=2^{4\log_25}=2^{\log_2625}=625.$$